# How to delete directories where files within directories don't have a certain regex match?

Tags: linux, shell

Say I have the following directories:

```
dir > subdir1 > k.txt > "Keep please"
    > subdir2 > l.txt > "Keep me"
    > subdir3 > m.txt > "Delete me"
    > subdir4 > n.txt > "remove"
```

I want to find an expression that will let me do a regex match on the contents within the file, and delete the subdirectories that do not have that string match. So in the example above, I would use something like `grep -r "Keep.*` for the files and them only `rm` subdir3. I want to end up with:

```
dir > subdir1 > k.txt > "Keep please"
    > subdir2 > l.txt > "Keep me"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shell script approach:-

```
#!/bin/ksh

for dir in <your directory name here>/*
do
        printf "Checking dir: ${dir}..."
        if grep -q "Keep" ${dir}/*
        then
                print " [Keep]"
                # do nothing
        else
                print " [Remove]"
                # rm -rf ${dir}
        fi
done
```

I commented `rm` statement, you can first run the script and carefully verify the `print` statement output to make sure it is picking the right directory names.